# Is homology an adjoint functor?

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Consider the homology functor $H$ defined (say) on the category of complexes of R-modules (where $R$ is unitary commutative ring). Does $H$ admits left or right adjoints? I know that homology preserves direct sums and direct limits, so it seems reasonable to think of it as a left adjoint.

I also believe that homology cannot be a right adjoint, since in general it does not preserve inverse limits. Is this correct?

Sorry if the question is naive, I'm studying homological algbera directly from a course in algebraic topology.

Comment: First of all, *which* homology? The entire graded object $H_\bullet(C) = \bigoplus_n H_n(C)$, as a functor $H_\bullet  : {\sf Ch}(R) \to {\sf Mod}(R)^{\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: @Fosco The one you prefer, I'm used to work with the graded object, but the question makes senses also for the functors $H_q$ for every $q\in \mathbb{Z}$. [Ciao kb]

Comment: Ciao, have you tried to use the adjoint functor theorem in some form? If $H$ is cocontinuous between locally presentable categories, it has a right adjoint; incidentally, you have a formula for such right adjoint, $R\cong\text{Lan}_H(\text{id}_{{\sf Ch}(R)})$.

Comment: When you say "direct limits", do you mean "colimits of directed diagrams" or "colimits"? Homology does not preserve cokernels.

Comment: @ZhenLin The first one you say, as proven in Spanier 4.1.7, anyway if it does not preserve cokernels (counterexample?) it cannot be an adjoint.

Comment: @carciofo21 If you have a short exact sequence of complexes $0\to A_\bullet\to B_\bullet\to C_\bullet\to 0$, you have a long exact sequence $$...\to H_{n+1}(C)\to H_n(A)\to H_n(B)\to H_n(C)\to H_{n-1}(A)\to ...$$ But the boundary maps are not zero in general, so $H_n$ doesn't preserve kernels and cokernels.

Comment: Ah, of course, I should have said that; if a functor between preabelian categories is cocontinuous, it is right exact; homology is not.

Comment: Your reasoning is a little off, because while a left adjoint will respect products, you are asking about the converse. Of course, the validity of a statement and its converse are in general independent. As the answer points out, homology provides a counterexample to the converse of the statement that left adjoints respect products. That is, respecting products is not equivalent to being a left adjoint. That an implication implies its converse is a fallacy.

Comment: I find your late answer to be a little off. First, a left adjoit preserves colimits, and not necessarily products. Second, I am very well aware that if $p$ implies $q$, I can not logically deduce $q$ implies $p$. But that's not what I am doing. Nevertheless it is natural, when $q$ holds, to ask oneselves if it holds, in that specific case, because already $p$ does. This is what I asked, and the answer by Pedro Tamaroff and the comments answered completely my question.

Comment: While your question has merit, and the answer appears to be good, as it's interesting to consider the possibility of the converse, still, the reasoning you provided was fallacious. That is, that $a\implies b$ **does not** suggest, nor is it natural, that we then think of $b$ as an $a$, roughly.

Comment: @Cpc What is the point of your comment? I have explained enough what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As comments have pointed out, homology does not preserve cokernels for example. The functors that *are* adjoints, however, and this is a bit more important for example when you're doing model theory and homotopy theory with objects with a differential, are the boundary and cycles functor.

Namely, the functor from the category of complexes $\textsf {Ch}$ that assigns $C$ to $Z_n(C)$ is in fact of the form $\hom_{\textsf {Ch}}(S^n,C)$ where $S^n$ is the complex generated by a single element $z$ in degree $n$ with $dz=0$. Similarly, the functor $C\longmapsto B_n(C)$ is of the form $\hom_{\textsf {Ch}}(D^{n+1},C)$ where $D^{n+1}$ is the complex with two generators $x$ and $y$ in degrees $n+1$ and $n$ and with $dx=y$. The natural inclusion $S^n\subseteq D^{n+1}$ then induces the inclusion map $B_n(Z) \subseteq Z_n(C)$, and homology is, at least, a `quotient of representable functors.'